# Send review to google play store without leaving app

Tags: java, android, android-intent, user-feedback

I know how to open the google play store to rate my app, but I was wondering if its possible to let the user write their review/rate my app from a popup within my app. Then using some kind of intent to send the information to the google play store. Essentially making it easier for a user to rate the app.

See an example of the pop up below.

[image: example]

Comment: no google doesn't allow to do this... this will lead to a false ratings on playstore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this programmatically. Developers could take advantage of every user downloading there app and rating it automatically

Answer (score 1):

Sending user ratings direct to Google Play is not possible as of now. The above snapshot can be used to check user reviews and track their feedback to your own server.

Though you can g+ direct from the app.